# Tinymce - Is it possible to get caret position of textarea corresponding to WYSIWYG Editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, position, wysiwyg, caret

I'm wondering if we can get the real caret position of textarea when the fake cursor is in certain position under WYSIWYG Editor?

To better understand the question, please see the image below

[image]
Under WYSIWYG mode, when the cursor is after **s**, we get position **53**. and when the cursor is after **t**, we get position **79**.

The code would be something like...

```js
function getRealCaretPosition() {
    // all the dirty work goes here
}

// Ctrl + Q
if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 81) {
    var pos = getRealCaretPosition();
    alert(pos);
}
```

Is this possible to be achieved, in theory?

Comment: I think that Tinymce just updates the innerHTML of the textarea behind the scenes, so it doesn't really have its own caret position. You'd have to figure out what was causing the discrepancy by understanding the Tinymce source code and have your function account for it.

Answer (score 2):

`window.getSelection()` will give you the current selection point, then from here treewalk backwards until the start of your node, adding lengths of all text nodes encountered.

```
function walkback(node, stopAt) {
    if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) { // go to last child
        while (node && node.childNodes.length > 0) {
            node = node.childNodes[node.childNodes.length - 1];
        }
    } else if (node.previousSibling) { // else go to previous node
        node = node.previousSibling;
    } else if (node.parentNode) { // else go to previous branch
        while (node && !node.previousSibling && node.parentNode) {
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        if (node === stopAt) return;
        node = node.previousSibling;
    } else { // nowhere to go
        return;
    }
    if (node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) return node;
        if (node === stopAt) return;
        return walkback(node, stopAt);
    }
    return;
}

function getRealCaretPosition() {
    var sel = window.getSelection(), // current selection
        pos = sel.anchorOffset, // get caret start position
        node = sel.anchorNode; // get the current #text node
    while (node = walkback(node, myContentEditableElement)) {
        pos = pos + node.data.length; // add the lengths of the previous text nodes
    }
    return pos;
}
```

You will need to check that the current selection is actually within your *HTMLElement* of interest too, of course.

Comment: wow...thanks. but on my first attemp...`if (node.childNodes....node is null`. I'll take a closer look at this.

Comment: This method is totally different to [`selectionStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange), etc. on an `<input>`, so you can't just assume the selection is where you want it (maybe they've highlighted a different bit of the page). You may want to convert the [_Selection_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Selection) to a [_Range_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) (`.getRangeAt(0)`) and use `.startContainer` as initial `node` if you find ranges easier to get your head around than selections.

Comment: `node is null` was caused by empty content on the first call to function `getRealCaretPosition`. However, I did a simple test from my example --- put cursor after `s`, hit `ctrl+q`, returned `3158` or `3755`, while the actual code is only <50 length long. Well it actually always returns those 2 numbers, no matter what the content is. I'll consider your last comment and give it another try.

Comment: window in this context should be the tinymce iframe window - which you get using tinmyce.get('your_editor_id').getWin()

Comment: @user1643156 That sounds very much like it is counting all `#text` nodes to the beginning of the document. Check that the _Selection_'s node is contained within your place of interest (element passed as `stopAt`). This is probably due to that it is in an `<iframe>` so see [Thariama's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053219/tinymce-is-it-possible-to-get-caret-position-of-textarea-corresponding-to-wysi/15053756#comment21179825_15053756).

Comment: well, I changed to iframe window, now it returns the correct caret position, but of the rich editor, not of the actual code in the textarea. `123<strong>4|56</strong>789` returns `4` instead of `12`. :(

Comment: Oh - I misunderstood the original question. This can still be achieved by "walking back" but could be a lot more complicated, so here's my question - are you happy to include all opening and closing tags? i.e. `'<a>fo|o</a>bar'` becomes `<a>fo</a>` and then position `9` (this is a simple(er) _Range_ operation). If you don't want closing tags, then you can use `new XMLSerializer()` to serialise intermediate elements and _Range_ and _String_ methods to cut off the opening/closing tags (much more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a topic covered on tinyMCE illustrating this:

```
var inst = getInstanceById('editor/elementid');
var myBookmark = inst.getBookmark();

// do something, move the cursor position
inst.moveToBookmark(myBookmark);
```

[Source](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1009): Check other solution from here, if these dont work.

Comment: From there we can insert content....the problem is how we get the `number` of `caret position` in textarea.